# Nginx Ingress how to match with prefix but remove prefix when proxied to upstream

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I wanted my ingress to accept only two path, for example:

1. /path/prefix/resource/delete
2. /path/prefix/resource/put

on the pod/service part, pod accept

1. /resource/delete
2. /resource/put

how to configure Ingress to achieve this?

BTW, `/path/prefix(/|$)(.*)` is not an option, because this path will accept all path leading with `/path/prefix`

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just use /path/prefix(resource/[a-z]+) and then point the rewrite-target to /$1 like described here: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this can be very easy:

/path/prefix/(resource/delete|resource/put)$

then add `$1` to your rewrite-target.

@luke, I need to exactly match the path, not prefix leading match, this is why I can't use `[a-z]+` match